# Html client downloaded html text differs from original (symbols)

Tags: html

Hello I created a html file with some text in it. A client downloads the html file and the text looks different from original.

original:

> Kalvarijų

after:

> KalvarijÅ³

The last chars are changed. The encoding is set to match language.
Code :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style>
a:link {
    color: blue;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
<p>
Linkėjimai / Regards,<br>
Benas Sinevičius<br>
Programinės įrangos inžinierius / Software engineer<br>
<br>
UAB „ASPA“<br>
Mob. <a href="tel:+370 634 20 174">+370 634 20 174</a><br>
El. p. <a href="mailto:benas@aspa.lt">benas@aspa.lt</a><br>
<br>
Kalvarijų 125, Vilnius<br>
Tel.: <a href="tel:+370 68 66 9288">+370 68 66 9288</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the charset and try again

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

...

Comment: Can u post some code? It looks like some problems with the charset.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this HTML entity instead when outputting the 'u with ogonek'

`&#371;`

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0173/index.htm